Docker Image won't build in Azure DevOps but builds in Visual Studio 2022
Here is my dockerfile that I created using Visual Studio 2022:
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["backend/backend.csproj", "backend/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./backend/backend.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/backend"
RUN dotnet build "./backend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./backend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]

My file structure is set up like this:
->Backend.csproj
 |
  ->Various project files and folders
  ->DockerFile

When the pipelines builds in Azure we get this error:

##[error]#2 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
##[error]#3 DONE 0.2s
##[error]#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
##[error]#4 transferring context: 2B done
##[error]#4 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#5 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
##[error]#5 DONE 0.1s
##[error]#6 [internal] load build context
##[error]#6 transferring context: 68.54kB 0.0s done
##[error]#6 DONE 0.1s
##[error]#7 [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0@sha256:02fdc848bbda5d57d9211a72c99bd665b421206002d66b8bc2cc0b2297c227fa
##[error]#7 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0@sha256:02fdc848bbda5d57d9211a72c99bd665b421206002d66b8bc2cc0b2297c227fa
0.0s done
##[error]#7 sha256:784e7bf6f3d8d3224492fc1b69030a48b7698ab7f87061bcb9cdc269941a3a60
2.22kB / 2.22kB done
##[error]#7 sha256:1effa123c762f7f70587193ac9ed4b30255aae043abb6587a639a5339a8b9faf
5.67kB / 5.67kB done
##[error]#7 sha256:02fdc848bbda5d57d9211a72c99bd665b421206002d66b8bc2cc0b2297c227fa
1.08kB / 1.08kB done
##[error]#7 CANCELED
##[error]#8 [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src
##[error]#8 CACHED
##[error]#9 [build 3/7] COPY [backend/backend.csproj, backend/]
##[error]#9 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 2686415c-d675-4aa2-a9d0-5b8f2b68eac4::pvmze5n8ahasa8psyougi22ap:
"/backend/backend.csproj": not found
##[error]#10 [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
##[error]#10 DONE 0.0s
##[error]------
##[error] > [build 3/7] COPY [backend/backend.csproj, backend/]:
##[error]------
##[error]Dockerfile:12
##[error]--------------------
##[error]  10 |     ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
##[error]  11 |     WORKDIR /src
##[error]  12 | >>> COPY ["backend/backend.csproj", "backend/"]
##[error]  13 |     RUN dotnet restore "./backend/backend.csproj"
##[error]  14 |     COPY . .
##[error]--------------------
##[error]ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref
2686415c-d675-4aa2-a9d0-5b8f2b68eac4::pvmze5n8ahasa8psyougi22ap:
"/backend/backend.csproj": not found
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

When I run the build in VS 2022 it builds the container and works just fine.  When I check it into Azure, the build fails with this error.  I have tried to adjust the path on line 12 by putting ./backend as well as others without any luck.  What are we doing wrong? I though the docker support was easier in VS.


Please share the yaml file you used to build your docker image in DevOps. 2. Please set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and use this agent to run your pipeline. If it works, the issue may be related to the environment. If it doesn't work, there is something to do with your pipeline.



ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 2686415c-d675-4aa2-a9d0-5b8f2b68eac4::pvmze5n8ahasa8psyougi22ap: "/backend/backend.csproj

The cause of the issue is that when you use the Docker task in Azure DevOps Pipeline, the working directory will be set to the same path as the dockerfile by default.
From your file structure, the dockerfile is in the next folder level of the .csproj directory. In this case, it will not be able to find the .csproj file.
To solve this issue, you need to move the dockerfile file to the same level as Backend.csproj file.
For example:
->dockerfile
->Backend.csproj
  |
   ->Various project files and folders

Then you can change the Copy command in dockerfile.
COPY ["backend.csproj", "backend/"]

In this case, the Backend.csproj will be found in the docker build task.
In the following docker build step, you may encounter the following error at dotnet build line:

CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

To solve this issue, you need to copy the project file to the path: /src/backend
For example:
COPY . /src/backend

dockerfile sample:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["backend.csproj", "backend/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./backend/backend.csproj"
COPY . /src/backend
WORKDIR "/src/backend"
RUN dotnet build "./backend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./backend.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backend.dll"]

